# Auto log-out sequence based on inactivity on desktop devices

Tags: authentication

Applications that monitor user activity may log out of the app if there is no user activity in the app for more than `kLogoutInterval` period. This value could be 1 or 5 or 10 15 minutes based on the type of the app.

The question is however — how do you store the timestamp? Do you store the timestamp in the memory using some `ActivityManager` singleton class? OR for every activity, you would update the timestamp in the keychain? OR any other pointers?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the question is — is this timeout filed critical? Can it be simply exposed in the memory? Does it need to be stored in a secured asset like a keychain? What is the overall risk assessment for using this timestamp casually?

Comment: I don't understand how this is an information security question.  This seems like a programming question specific to the language you're developing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an attacker can write to specific memory locations to prevent logout, you're already severely compromised.  Any attacker that can change arbitrary memory can write arbitrary code to it.

If an attacker can read specific memory locations, you're also very likely severely compromised if you store anything in memory you wouldn't want world+dog to know.